# Prevent ActiveRecord to round decimals

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have this code:

```
Payment.select('payments.*, (payment.amount * 0.1) as total_amount')
```

and when total_amount is equal to 0.1(checked in mysql console) ActiveRecord returns 0. How to prevent ActiveRecord to round decimals? Thanks in advance

Comment: What datatype does `total_amount` field have?

Comment: `total_amount` needs to be a `float` if you want to have decimal values.

Comment: If my answer seems working for you,then please accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `total_amount` datatype is an `integer` then it wont accepts float values,so in your case `total_amount` datatype needs to set to `float`.

And also if you are wondering how to change it to `float`,and if you are not worried of the data being lost,then I would recommend `rake db:rollback`

Later open your `create_payments` migration file and edit the datatype to float.And don't forget to do `rake db:migrate` after that.